# XDocument can't parse XML

Tags: c#, xml

I get `ArgumentException: Non-whitespace text appears directly in the document.`

For this is the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><result>
            <value>
            <score>12</score>
            <username>Carlos</username>
            </value>
            <value>
            <score>6</score>
            <username>Jimmy</username>
            </value></result>
```

I tried formatting all in one line, but the error still comes up.

And this is how I try to load it

```
#Object from Unity 3D
WWW www = new WWW(url);
XDocument doc = new XDocument(www.text);
```

Why?

Comment: What is `www.text`? What type is it? I suspect you are invoking [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352589%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and as you can see in the docs, it does *not* expect the source code of the Xml document for its arguments.

Comment: Do you mean XDocument.Parse(www.text)?

Comment: For future reference, the best place to start is by reading the tooltip for the method or constructor that is failing. Documentation is extremely important to write, but more important to _read_.

Answer (score 3):

In order to create an `XDocument` from a string of xml, you need to use the static [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, for example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(www.text);
```

However, since you have a URL, you can just use the static [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
```